# How do I send a build log with email notification for drone build

Tags: java, spring-boot, continuous-integration, drone.io

I want to send an attachment of build log with the email notification via drone build. For email notification, I am using I am using "drillster/drone-email" plugin for sending build email notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out: https://github.com/jjasghar/drone-example-yamls/blob/main/kind-exec.drone.yaml#L5-L14

If you remove the `when` clause you'll get an email for each run.